# How do I control radio button in splinter Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

i have two options to press the button, i want the second option (which data-value is 2. the code of the page is :

```
<div class="a-C a-C-bg" data-name="pco" data-value="1" role="radio" aria-checked="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><span class="a-C-Qa"></span><div class="a-C-Q">הודעת טקסט (SMS)</div></div>

<div class="a-C a-C-bg a-C-q" data-name="pco" data-value="2" aria-checked="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" tabindex="0"><span class="a-C-Qa"></span><div class="a-C-Q">שיחת טלפון אוטומטית</div></div>
```

i have tried:

```
one= browser.find_by_name('pco')
two=browser.find_by_tag('pco')
three= browser.find_by_value('pco')
four= browser.find_by_css('-webkit-user-select:none;')

print one
print two
print three
print four
```

but it all prints null (so i cant control the radio button).
also tried:

```
browser.choose('pco', '2')
```

but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
browser.find_by_xpath('//div[@data-name="pco"][@data-value="2"]').first.click()
```

Comment: i have got an error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't notice that you use `Splinter`. Answer updated